# how to run a shell script from Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

How to run a shell script from Azure Data Factory. Inside the shell script I am trying to execute an hql file like below:

```
/usr/bin/hive -f "wasbs://hivetest@batstorpdnepetradev01.blob.core.windows.net/hivetest/extracttemp.hql" > 
wasbs://hivetest@batstorpdnepetradev01.blob.core.windows.net/hivetest/extracttemp.csv
```

My hql file is stored inside a Blob Storage and I want to execute it and collect the result into  a csv file and store it back to Blob Storage . This entire script is stored in shell script which also in a Blob Storage. NowIi want to execute in a Azure Data Factory in hive activity. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Hadoop hive activity in ADF. Please take a look at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-hadoop-hive). And you could build your pipeline with [ADF V2 UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal).